# Ошибка при загрузке приложения в itunes connect через xcode - "The archive contains nothing that can be signed"

Tags: ios, xcode

Ошибка при загрузке приложения в itunes connect через xcode.

> The archive contains nothing that can be signed. Verify that your
>   build process has compiled binaries and copied in bundled resources.
>
> log: Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error
>   Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=13 "The archive contains
>   nothing that can be signed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The
>   archive contains nothing that can be signed.,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Verify that your build process has
>   compiled binaries and copied in bundled resources.}

[image: Screen]

Comment: Добавьте подробностей. Где проект находится? Как делали и на чем? Что использовано? Хоть какие-то наводки.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

build settings -- architectures  --

Edit to

1386 x86_64 armv7 armv64

And works with you successfully

Comment: رجاء ترجم إلى الروسية ، أو على الأقل إلى الإنجليزية. [edit]

Comment: architectures --
1386 x86_64 armv7 armv64